# Create lines by id from two sets of points

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have two sets of points and I want to connect them to form lines by the id of the points. I.E. I have the following feature classes of points:

FC_1

```
ID EASTING NORTHING
A1 222222  222222
A2 333333  333333
```

FC_2

```
ID EASTING NORTHING
A1 222822  222222
A2 333933  333333
```

I want to create a line feature class that joins by ID, so one line for ID A1 and another line for ID A2. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would do this using an arcpy.da.SearchCursor to read the end point values and simultaneously an arcpy.da.UpdateCursor @SHAPE token to create polyline geometries that join them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@PolyGeo's suggestion is the most elegant way of doing this, but if you are not familiar with arcpy/scripting in general, the steps given below should do the job:

1. Create two point layers for each FC by using **Make XY Event Layer**
2. Merge them by making sure you will have ID values in one field
3. Use Point to Line tool (after ArcGIS 10.1) by selecting your ID field as **Line Field (optional)**